# Simultaneous dynamic and static NAT not working

Tags: cisco, nat, port-forwarding

Cisco 4200 series running IOS XE with a single public IP address and dynamic NAT, which works just fine.  I am trying to add Static NAT to access a server (map external port `XX` to internal port `YY`. Below, `GigabitEthernet0/0/0` is the WAN interface, `a.b.c.d` is the server I am trying access from the outside world.

```
ip nat inside source route-map nat-internet interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 overload

ip nat inside source static tcp a.b.c.d YY interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 XX

ip access-list extended internet-acl
 permit ip a.b.c.0 0.0.0.255 any

route-map nat-internet permit 1
 match ip address internet-acl
 match interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
```

This configuration doesn't work. I can ping the server `a.b.c.d` and access services at port `YY` from the router, but a connection from the outside world to the WAN IP at port `XX` times out. Port scanning shows the port to be closed.

Here is the output of `sh ip nat translations`

```
Pro  Inside global         Inside local          Outside local         Outside global
tcp  <WAN-IP>:XX           a.b.c.d:YY            ---                   ---
```

EDIT: I see the error in that the ACL for dynamic NAT includes the host I'm attempting to Static NAT (now fixed). The complete configuration is:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 negotiation auto

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 no ip address
 negotiation auto

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 ip address 10.60.2.2 255.255.255.0

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.4
 encapsulation dot1Q 4
 ip address 10.60.4.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.9
 encapsulation dot1Q 9
 ip address 10.60.9.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 10.60.20.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside

ip nat inside source static tcp 10.60.9.31 <YY> interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 <XX>
ip nat inside source route-map NAT-Internet interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0         overload
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 10.60.6.0 255.255.255.0 10.60.4.1
ip route 10.60.8.0 255.255.255.0 10.60.4.1
ip route 10.60.10.0 255.255.255.0 10.60.4.1

ip access-list extended Internet-ACL
 permit ip 10.60.6.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.60.8.0 0.0.0.255 any
 permit ip 10.60.10.0 0.0.0.255 any


route-map NAT-Internet permit 10 
match ip address Internet-ACL
match interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
```

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: remove the `match ip address` part of the route-map. Please provide the complete (sanitized) configuration as there may be other problems.

Comment: @RickyBeam posted. I see the issue, which I've fixed. Upon connection, I see a translation show up in `show ip nat translations inside 10.60.9.31`.  However, the connection times out (I am able to access that machine at port 22 fine from within the router, as mentioned in the post). I'm mapping local port `YY`=22 (SSH) on 10.60.9.31 to an outside port.